# load file to memory by block of 256kb

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark

I'm studying [Blocked sort-based indexing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/blocked-sort-based-indexing-1.html) and the algorithm talks about loading files by some block of 32 or 64kb because disk reading is by block so it is efficient.

My first question is how am I supposed to load file by block?buffer reader of 64kb? But if I use java input stream, whether or not this optimization has already beed done and I can just tream the stream?

I actually use apache spark, so whether or not sparkContext.textFile() does this optimization? what about spark streaming?

Comment: Which file system do you use to store your files? Also, what is the format of your files?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez regular pc storage system, but I can also use Hadoop, and the file would be txt but I would like to know the different solution if they are different for json, csv.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think on the JVM you have any direct view onto the file system that would make it meaningful to align reads and block-sizes. Also there are various kinds of drives and many different file systems now, and block sizes would most likely vary or even have little effect on the total I/O time.

The best performance would probably be to use `java.nio.FileChannel`, and then you can experiment with reading `ByteBuffer`s of given block sizes to see if it makes any performance difference. I would guess the only effect you see is that the JVM overhead for very small buffers matters more (extreme case, reading byte by byte).

You may also use the file-channel's `map` method to get hold of a `MappedByteBuffer`.